# influxdb2 / grafana - top x of timeserie values

Tags: grafana, influxdb, influxdb-2

I search a way to get the top X of value from timeseries influxdb:

the granularity is one minute.
Csv imported:

```
#datatype measurement,tag,tag,double,double,double,dateTime:number
HDD,server,hdd_id,Read_IOPS,Write_IOPS,Read_ms,time
HDD,srv1,hdd1,35,33,1,1671233940
HDD,srv1,hdd1,24,69,1,1671234000
HDD,srv1,hdd1,97,57,2,1671234060
HDD,srv1,hdd1,30,78,2,1671234120
HDD,srv1,hdd1,53,83,2,1671234180
HDD,srv1,hdd1,56,85,2,1671234240
HDD,srv1,hdd1,32,25,22,1671234300
HDD,srv1,hdd1,29,89,6,1671234360
HDD,srv1,hdd1,33,41,1,1671234420
HDD,srv1,hdd1,22,15,8,1671234480
HDD,srv1,hdd1,24,95,4,1671234540
…
HDD,srv1,hdd2,35,33,1,1671233940
HDD,srv1,hdd2,24,69,1,1671234000
HDD,srv1,hdd2,97,57,2,1671234060
HDD,srv1,hdd2,30,78,2,1671234120
HDD,srv1,hdd2,53,83,2,1671234180
HDD,srv1,hdd2,56,85,2,1671234240
HDD,srv1,hdd2,32,25,22,1671234300
HDD,srv1,hdd2,29,89,6,1671234360
HDD,srv1,hdd2,33,41,1,1671234420
HDD,srv1,hdd2,22,15,8,1671234480
HDD,srv1,hdd2,24,95,4,1671234540
…
HDD,srv1,hdd3,35,33,1,1671233940
HDD,srv1,hdd3,24,69,1,1671234000
HDD,srv1,hdd3,97,57,2,1671234060
HDD,srv1,hdd3,30,78,2,1671234120
HDD,srv1,hdd3,53,83,2,1671234180
HDD,srv1,hdd3,56,85,2,1671234240
HDD,srv1,hdd3,32,25,22,1671234300
HDD,srv1,hdd3,29,89,6,1671234360
HDD,srv1,hdd3,33,41,1,1671234420
HDD,srv1,hdd3,22,15,8,1671234480
HDD,srv1,hdd3,24,95,4,1671234540
…
```

I try with this query (flux influxdb2), but only 2 point are displayed on the grafana dashboard:

-> I would like to display for example the top 2 of hdd more busiest for Read_IOPS

```
import "strings"

|> from(bucket: v.bucket)
|> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == “HDD”)
|> drop(columns: [“server”])
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == “HDD_Read_IOPS”)
|> map(fn: (r) => ({r with newhddid: strings.substring(v: r.hdd_id, start: 0, end: 4)}))
|> group(columns: [“newhddid”])
|> highestMax(n: 2, groupColumns: [“newhddid”])
|> aggregateWindow(column: “_value”, every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean)
```

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: highestMax(n: 2, groupColumns: [“newhddid”]) will return 2 highest records. That's why you will see only 2 point are displayed. You could change the parameter to display more records.

Comment: I already tried. the graph is not complete. the series "_time" is truncated